# PHP - How to turn an array like "eg1","eg2","eg3" into "+eg1","+eg2","+eg3"?

Tags: php, string, implode

I am working on a search feature for my site.

At the moment I am taking a string from a single input and then cleaning it into a string like "eg1 eg2 eg3".

Here is the code for that :

```
$pattern = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['search']);
$pattern = strip_tags($pattern); 
$pattern = trim ($pattern);
$pattern = explode(' ', $pattern);
$pattern = implode(" ", $pattern);
```

What i would like to do is take the original string and at either the point where it is in an array (after the explode) append + in front of every value.

I have been looking through the documentation on the functions I have been making use of but cannot quite seem to see how they could work in this way. This is being that i can turn the string to "eg1 +eg2 +eg3" but i cannot get the plus in front of the first result?

If anyone could point out the relevant function of possibly provide me with an example on how i could go about this task, it would be greatly appreciated!

Any input/suggestion/feedback is welcome, thank you!

Please don't flame and go RTM!!!!! Because i have and i cannot seem to find what i am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the missing + as the first character in the resultant string:

```
$pattern = "+".implode(" +", $pattern);
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your reply! That does seem like the most logical and least intensive approach to me. I appreciate the simplicity in this :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$pattern = implode(" +", $pattern);
```

anyway I don't see any point to make an array and then convert it back to string. `str_replace(" ", " +", $str)` should be enough

Comment: This will not prefix the first array value with a `+`

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! But as stated by the writer of the previous comment this does not exactly work out as the first word does not get the + :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:
$pattern = explode(' ', $pattern);
$pattern = '+'.implode(' +', $pattern);

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this was already covered by @shannonman.